# Unable to mock functions in when running mockmvc test

Tags: mockito, mockmvc

I am writting test case of my controller using mockmvc

```
@Mock
private AService aService;

@InjectMocks
private AController aController;



@BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(aController)
                .setCustomArgumentResolvers(putAuthenticationPrincipal)  // for passing the authentication principal
                .build();
    }
```

now when i trying to test

```
@Test
    public void testfunction() throws Exception {
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  Mockito.when(aService.getAccount(Mockito.anyString())).thenThrow(new Exception("not avalible"));
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/account/{id}", id)
....      
   }
```

In this the aService.getAccount() is not getting mock. that is why I am not getting the desired result..

I didn't understand why the mocking of function isn't working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In a `@WebMvcTest`, you should not create a mock of your controller. Spring needs to create a controller in it’s context, and inject collaborating services into it.

To do that:

- annotate the test class with `@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)`
- annotate collaborating services with `@MockBean`, not `@Mock`